# Package biblatex Warning: Nested notes on input line

Tags: biblatex, footer

I'm trying to use `\footcite` command to which Overleaf shows the following warning: `Package biblatex Warning: Nested notes on input line 10`. How can I get rid of the warning? Am I missing some necessary packages? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\title{MWE}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Inline citation: \cite{Ahlfors78}. 
This is a footnote\footnote{Like this\footcite{Ahlfors78}}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `bibfile.bib` consists of the sole entry:

```
@book{Ahlfors78,
    AUTHOR = {Ahlfors, Lars V.},
    TITLE = {Complex analysis},
    SERIES = {International Series in Pure and Applied Mathematics},
    EDITION = {Third},
    NOTE = {An introduction to the theory of analytic functions of one complex variable},
    PUBLISHER = {McGraw-Hill Book Co., New York},
    YEAR = {1978},
    PAGES = {xi+331},
    ISBN = {0-07-000657-1},
    MRCLASS = {30-01},
    MRNUMBER = {510197},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What do you expect the output from `\footnote{Like this\footcite{Ahlfors78}}` to be? A footnote within a footnote? (That is what the warning is about) Or are you looking for `\footnote{Like this\fullcite{Ahlfors78}}`? Or just `\footnote{Like this\cite{Ahlfors78}}`?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! I think I get what I'm doing wrong. I basically need `\footnote{Like this~\cite{Ahlfors78}}`. I thought `\footcite` is appropriate, but I guess I can just proceed with the regular `\cite` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\footcite` means "start a footnote and put the citation in that footnote". If you use `\footnote` then you also start a footnote. Therefore the combination `\footnote{Like this\footcite{Ahlfors78}}` means "start a footnote, print *Like this* in that footnote, then start another footnote inside of the current footnote, then put the citation in that footnote-inside-the-footnote".

LaTeX complains about the nested footnote - while it is not impossible in principle to nest footnotes you need a special setup for this. From the comments it was clear that this was also not desired, and just `\footnote{Like this\cite{Ahlfors78}}` (with the meaning "start a footnote, then print the citation inside that footnote) was sufficient.